# Enviar dados para guardiões no angular

Tags: angular, typescript

Preciso fazer um guard para verificar se um usuário possui permissão as telas do sistema.

Tenho um array guardado no localstorage que me informa as permissoes de um usuário.

Exemplo: [1,2,5], onde o número é o id da tela que a pessoa pode acessar.

Gostaria de saber se tem como eu estar enviando dados do meu arquivo de rotas para o guardião.

Algo como:

```
{ path: 'custofixo', component: CustofixoComponent, data:{idtela: 1}, canActivate:[PermissoesTelaGuard], pathMatch: 'full' }
```

Tem como recuperar esse idtela no meu guardião?

Comment: Voce pode inserir o router ou o activatedRoute no constructor do seu guard e pegar a informacao la.

Comment: Não queria ser chato, mas o localstorage não é um jeito legal de se fazer isso, qualquer um pode abrir as ferramentas de desenvolvedor e adicionar números ao array de permissões facilmente. O jeito mais correto e tradicional é possuir um serviço back-end cuidando destas permissões e você fazer um get no AuthGuard com um array que veio de lá. Depois, isso é fácil, basta verificar no `canLoad()` ou `canActivate()` se o array possui o id da tela que está acessando

Answer (score 0):

Pode usar um serviço que disponibilize o toke ou as permissões explicitamente.

## user.service.ts

```
...
getPermissions(){
   const currentUser = localStorage.getItem(currentUser);
   return currentUser.permissions; // Aqui você retorna o array com suas permissões
}
...
```

## app.guard.ts

```
 constructor(private userService: UserService) { }

 canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
    const idTela = route.snapshot.data['idtela'];
    const permissions = this.userService.getPermissions();
    if (!permissions.includes(idTela)) {
      alert('Activation blocked');
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
```

Acredito que isso resolva.

Boa sorte!